# snowpark to merge custom array along with dataframe in python

Tags: python, dataframe, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

How to merge the processed array to `snowpark` dataframe?

Dataframe I have doesn't include the user agent details. So I planned to use the python sheet along with `snowpark` package. Hence I used `to_local_iterator` for the selected col and I got the console output. But I want that output to be merged or joined with the dataframe.

Code:

```
import snowflake.snowpark as snowpark
from snowflake.snowpark.functions import col,call_udf
from user_agents import parse
import pandas as pd 

    
def main(session: snowpark.Session): 
    
    tableName = 'X'
    dataframe = session.table(tableName).filter(col("X") == 'X')
    #dataframe = session.table(tableName)
    df_selected = dataframe.select("X")
    arr = []

    for row in df_selected.to_local_iterator():
     print(parse(str(row)).browser.family + " " + parse(str(row)).browser.version_string)
     arr.append(parse(str(row)).browser.family + " " + parse(str(row)).browser.version_string)
     
    return dataframe
```

what is the best way to merge arr array with the dataframe?

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
import snowflake.snowpark as snowpark
from snowflake.snowpark.functions import col, call_udf
from user_agents import parse
import pandas as pd

def main(session: snowpark.Session):
    
    tableName = 'X'
    dataframe = session.table(tableName).filter(col("X") == 'X')
    
    # Extract the user agent details and create a new column
    udf_parse_user_agent = call_udf(parse, col("X").cast("STRING"))
    dataframe_with_user_agent = dataframe.withColumn("user_agent_details", udf_parse_user_agent)
    
    # Show the DataFrame with the new user agent details column
    dataframe_with_user_agent.show()

    return dataframe_with_user_agent
```